# concat + groupby + apply in multiple columns in panda dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, concatenation

I have the two following dataframes:

df1

```
ticker       date       return      high_low      turnover
CRM         2017-01-03  0.018040    0.026957    5.722346e+08
MSFT        2017-01-03  -0.003344   0.011428    1.295037e+09
CRM         2017-01-04  0.024198    0.032646    6.762756e+08
MSFT        2017-01-04  -0.002881   0.010142    1.329482e+09
CRM         2017-01-05  -0.000275   0.015580    3.417927e+08
```

df2:

```
ticker       date       return      high_low    turnover
CRM         2017-01-03  0.018040    0.026957    5.722318e+08
MSFT        2017-01-03  -0.003344   0.011509    1.295037e+09
CRM         2017-01-04  0.024198    0.032575    6.761264e+08
MSFT        2017-01-04  -0.002881   0.010142    1.329480e+09
CRM         2017-01-05  -0.000275   0.015580    3.417930e+08
```

And I have the following code working.
But I guess is possible to simplify the four last lines in just one. Doing the concat+groupby+apply of the three columns in just one line.

```
def get_min_absvalue(values):
    return min(values, key = abs)

#simplify the following 4 lines in 1?
consolidated_return=(pd.concat((df1,df2),ignore_index=True,sort=False).groupby(['date','ticker'])['return'].apply(lambda x: get_min_absvalue(x)).reset_index())
consolidated_high_low=(pd.concat((df1,df2),ignore_index=True,sort=False).groupby(['date','ticker'])['high_low'].apply(lambda x: get_min_absvalue(x)).reset_index())
consolidated_turnover=(pd.concat((df1,df2),ignore_index=True,sort=False).groupby(['date','ticker'])['turnover'].apply(lambda x: get_min_absvalue(x)).reset_index())

merged = consolidated_return.merge(consolidated_high_low, on=['date', 'ticker']).merge(consolidated_turnover, on=['date', 'ticker'])
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Columns from `df1` & `df2`:

- create a `list` of column names

```
used_cols = ['return', 'high_low', 'turnover']
```

### List of DataFrames:

- Use list comprehension to create a list of DataFrames

```
df_list = [pd.concat((df1, df2), ignore_index=True, sort=False).groupby(['date', 'ticker'])[v].apply(lambda x: min(x, key=abs)) for v in used_cols]
```

#### Contents of `df_list`:

- These are of type `pandas.core.series.Series`

```
df_list[0]

date        ticker
2017-01-03  CRM       0.026957
            MSFT      0.011428
2017-01-04  CRM       0.032575
            MSFT      0.010142
2017-01-05  CRM       0.015580
Name: high_low, dtype: float64
```

### Use `concat` instead of `merge`:

- Easily combine `df_list` with `concat`

```
merged = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1).reset_index()
```

### Final DataFrame:

[image]

### Compare DataFrames created with new and original code:

```
merged_new == merged_old
```

[image]

## Final code:

- Only 3 lines of code compared to 6, and no repetitions.

```
used_cols = ['return', 'high_low', 'turnover']
df_list = [pd.concat((df1, df2), ignore_index=True, sort=False).groupby(['date', 'ticker'])[v].apply(lambda x: min(x, key=abs)) for v in used_cols]
merged = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a simple `min` aggregate call:

```
agg_df = (pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
              .groupby(['date','ticker'], as_index=False)
              .min()
         )

print(agg_df)
#         date ticker    return  high_low      turnover
# 0 2017-01-03    CRM  0.018040  0.026957  5.722318e+08
# 1 2017-01-03   MSFT -0.003344  0.011428  1.295037e+09
# 2 2017-01-04    CRM  0.024198  0.032575  6.761264e+08
# 3 2017-01-04   MSFT -0.002881  0.010142  1.329480e+09
# 4 2017-01-05    CRM -0.000275  0.015580  3.417927e+08

print(merged.eq(agg_df))
#    date  ticker  return  high_low  turnover
# 0  True    True    True      True      True
# 1  True    True    True      True      True
# 2  True    True    True      True      True
# 3  True    True    True      True      True
# 4  True    True    True      True      True
```

For true absolute value minimum aggregation:

```
agg_df = (pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
              .groupby(['date','ticker'], as_index=False)['return', 'high_low', 'turnover']
              .apply(lambda x: x.abs().min())
              .reset_index()
            )

print(agg_df)

#         date ticker    return  high_low      turnover
# 0 2017-01-03    CRM  0.018040  0.026957  5.722318e+08
# 1 2017-01-03   MSFT  0.003344  0.011428  1.295037e+09
# 2 2017-01-04    CRM  0.024198  0.032575  6.761264e+08
# 3 2017-01-04   MSFT  0.002881  0.010142  1.329480e+09
# 4 2017-01-05    CRM  0.000275  0.015580  3.417927e+08
```